# Does wx.DC line has events?

Tags: python, wxpython

A line created using the DrawLine method of wx.DC has the onClick and onMouseOver events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No wx.DC just draw to a device and those are all plain pixels, wx.DC doesn't track mouse events or any other events.

If you want such behavior you will have to track mouse movement on your drawing area and on click check which area it may have clicked e.g. if near by the line show a msg etc.